# Deploy a website on OVH using GitLab CI-CD

Tags: gitlab, cicd, ovh

I wonder for a personal project how to deploy a website on OVH using GitLab CI-CD. Indeed, I would like to develop on GitLab and then by each commit or merge on master trigger a pipeline that will deploy on OVH.

The fact is I have no idea how to do that because I consider myself as a beginner in pipelines.

I have some ideas but I would like your feedback on them.
Should I dockerize my app and then deploy it by the image on OVH ?
Should I only use the SFTP (as I do manually) to add new/all files ?
What about if I want to use linters to test my static code ?

I hope you will be helpful because it's kind a mess in my mind ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy a web application on OVH's infrastructure, here are the key steps to follow:

1. **Pipeline Initialization:** Start by creating a file named 'gitlab-ci.yml' at the root of your project. This file is essential for configuring and executing pipelines in GitLab.
2. **File Configuration:** In 'gitlab-ci.yml', define the tasks you plan to perform:

   - **Building the Application:** This is the phase where your code is compiled or prepared for deployment. If you're working on a ReactJS application, for example, this step will adapt your code for production.
   - **Deployment to the OVH Server:** This step involves transferring and launching your application on an OVH server.

   Here is a minimalist example for a ReactJS application (note that this example needs to be adapted according to the specifics of your application, and it is recommended to also include your application's tests):

   ```yaml
   stages:
     - build
     - deploy

   build project:
     stage: build
     image: node:16.15.1
     artifacts:
       paths:
         - build
       name: "artiReactApp"
       expire_in: 30 days
     script:
       - echo "Building package"
       - rm -rf build
       - npm install
       - CI=false npm run build
       - echo "Build successful"

   deploy prod:
     stage: deploy
     script:
       - apt-get update && apt-get install -y lftp
       - lftp -c "open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; rm -rf www/; mkdir www"
       - lftp -c "open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror -Rnev ./build /www --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
     only:
       - main
   ```

   Note: Be sure to adapt the paths (such as `/www`) according to the configuration of your FTP server at OVH.
3. **Setting Up Variables in GitLab:** To finalize, you need to add the necessary environment variables in GitLab. These are the $FTP_HOST, $FTP_USER, and $FTP_PASSWORD variables, which correspond to the address of your FTP server, your user ID, and your password, respectively. To do this, navigate in the GitLab interface under your project: Settings > CI/CD > Variables.

By following these steps, you will be able to efficiently deploy your content on an OVH server.

Good luck with this process!